# I need to calculate a limit using Euler number

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital, euler-mascheroni-constant

How would one evaluate this limit without using L'Hôpital's rule? What I know for sure is that this limit equals to zero, but I don’t know how to solve it.

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{2x-5}{2x-2}\right)^{4x^{2}} = 0
$$

Edit: This is Wolframalpha solution: https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/f6d89370-5d6b-44de-9f4e-0377dea18aad , but it uses the L'Hôpital's rule and I think it is a quite complicated solution.

Comment: Telling people you need something ASAP will not earn you any love around here.

Comment: "I was not present at the time they were doing that" Then read the relevant chapter of the textbook, or ask your fellow students for some notes.

Comment: @Rahul That is exactly what I have done, but the problem is, they did not encounter such problem during class and the teacher gave us these problems randomly. He did not solve them himself, so I am not sure if it even can be solved without the L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: @makulo123 hey There! You know your question has been put on hold. Next time if you asked a question, just write your own solution (doesn't matter if it's incomplete, wrong, or unrelated), it gives us the insight to look the question and understand your level and give you the best to your level ;) :) :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_\limits {n\to \infty} (1+\frac {x}{n})^n = e^x$

$\lim_\limits {x\to \infty} (\frac {2x-5}{2x-2})^{4x^2}\\
\lim_\limits {x\to \infty} (1 +\frac{-3}{2x-2})^{4x^2}$

Now $\lim_\limits {x\to \infty} (1 +\frac{-3}{2x-2})^{2x-2} = e^{-3}$

So, what do you have to do to get a factor like this out of the line above?

$\lim_\limits {x\to \infty} ((1 +\frac{-3}{2x-2})^{2x-2})^{2x+2}(1 +\frac{-3}{2x-2})^4\\
\lim_\limits {x\to \infty} (e^{-3})^{2x+2}(1 +\frac{-3}{2x-2})^4$

$0<e^{-3} < 1$

What I have done here is not rigorous.

But you can use the work above to say:

$0\le \lim_\limits {x\to \infty}(\frac {2x-5}{2x-2})^{4x^2} \le \lim_\limits {x\to \infty} e^{-6x}$

$\lim_\limits {x\to \infty}(\frac {2x-5}{2x-2})^{4x^2} = 0$ by the squeeze theorem.

Comment: You can't take the limit of  part of an expression, the take the limit of what remains (with exponents, &c.).

Comment: True, I have played a bit fast-and-loose.  But, It points us in a direction that is rigorous.

Comment: @doug-m Ok, thanks. But I don't quite understand this line:
$0<e^{-3} < 1$ How did we get this statement from the previous line?

Comment: $0<e^{-3}<1$ because $e>1$

Comment: Yes, thanks, I used a bit different aproach based on your solution: $\lim_\limits {x\to \infty}(e^{-3})^{2x+2}=\lim_\limits {x\to \infty}(e^{-6x-6})=\lim_\limits {x\to \infty}(e^{-6x})(e^{-6})=0$